# Keras Train Neural Network Dimension Value Error: expected to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1, 4)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

```
Python 3.6
Keras 2.2
Tensorflow 1.8 backend
```

I am having trouble training my neural network because I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected t_dense_3 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1, 4)
```

My neural network

```
>>> sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6)
>>> target_q_network = Sequential([
      Dense(40, input_shape=observation_shape, activation='relu', name='t_dense_1'),
      Dense(40, activation='relu', name='t_dense_2'),
      Dense(number_of_actions, activation='linear', name='t_dense_3')
    ])
>>> target_q_network.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)
>>> observation_shape
    (8,)

-----------------------------------------------------------------

(Pdb) target_q_network.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
t_dense_1 (Dense)            (None, 40)                360       
_________________________________________________________________
t_dense_2 (Dense)            (None, 40)                1640      
_________________________________________________________________
t_dense_3 (Dense)            (None, 4)                 164       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,164
Trainable params: 2,164
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

When I pass in values to the neural network an array of shape (1, 4) is returned:

```
(Pdb) env.reset()
array([-0.00126171,  0.94592496, -0.12780861,  0.35410735,  0.00146875, 0.02895054,  0.        ,  0.        ])
# Passing value into Neural Network
(Pdb) target_q_network.predict(env.reset().reshape(1,8))
array([[ 0.07440183,  0.03480911,  0.11266299, -0.08043154]], dtype=float32)
```

I am passing in `training_set` and `labels`

```
(Pdb) training_set.shape
(32, 8)
(Pdb) labels.shape
(32, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

The`'mean_squared_error'` loss function is probably expecting to receive a `(batch_sz x n_labels)` matrix of labels, but you are passing a `(batch_sz x 1 x n_labels)` matrix of labels, specifically with `labels.shape=(32, 1, 4)`. You just need to reshape your `labels` to have the shape `(batch_sz x n_labels)` so it has `labels.shape=(32, 4)`, which can then be properly compared to the neural network output.

Comment: I believe `tf.squeeze` is the function OP needs to use, which would get rid of that empty dimension.